# What triggers Azure Functions to reload the referenced assemblies?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I've been referencing external assemblies trying to work around the issue noted here: [Azure Function Cannot Load Portable Assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38314334/how-do-i-reference-a-portable-net-assembly-from-an-azure-cloud-function).  However, often my function does not seem to reflect the changes made to the functionName\bin assemblies.  I've intentionally referenced the wrong assemblies, and then reran the function.  I experience no change to what is logged (and I'm logging exceptions).

How do I force a complete reload of the Azure function?  Can I somehow see what Azure functions has as its "loaded" assemblies?

Comment: There also seems to be a consistent problem when updating the code in the App Service Editor, and then going and looking at the same code in the portal's Function App.  I can't find a consistent way to make the function app reflect the changes...

Comment: In the old portal I was able to start and stop the webjob (which is the same underlying SDK).  Is there some sort of CLI I can use instead of the GUI?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the only thing changing is the implementation and not the assembly identity (name, version, etc.), you'd indeed see this behavior as an assembly with a matching identity would already be loaded and that would be used.

Restarting your Function App site (under Function app settings > Go to app service settings > Restart) should trigger a host restart, which will force all assemblies to be reloaded.

You can also Kill the non-scm w3wp.exe process using Kudu (https://yourappname.scm.azurewebsites.net), under Process Explorer, which will also force a host restart.